# Cant get CanonicalForm for LUIS List entity in LuisResult/EntityRecommendation

Tags: botframework

Is there any way of getting the CanonicaForm in the C#-code after an intent? The LuisResult contains EntityRecommendation(s) but no info about which canonicalForm/sublist, just the written entity/synonym in EntityRecommendation.Entity and the name of the WHOLE List Entity in EntityRecommendation.Type.

Answer (score 1):

Assume "MyEntity" is a List entity, and one of its normalized values is "Check Out" with a synonym of "checkout"

If LUIS returns the synonym ("checkout") as the entity, the normalized value ("Check Out") can be retrieved as follows:

```
bool isEventType = result.TryFindEntity("MyEntity", out EntityRecommendation entityRecommendationEventType);

if (isEventType)
{
    stringSynonym = entityRecommendationEventType.Entity;
    stringNormalized = ((List<object>)entityRecommendationEventType.Resolution["values"])[0].ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve this from LUIS.  The only way you can do this is to export the list from LUIS and store it in your bot.  You can do this via the JSON file exported from LUIS.

Comment: when I am exporting the LUIS model as JSON I am gettign the list type of entity as null `{
      "text": "delhi is the national capital",
      "intent": "SynonymsIntent",
      "entities": []
    }` but in canonical form its as it is `{
          "canonicalForm": "Delhi",
          "list": [
            "new-delhi",
            "capital of india",
            "the national captial",
            "capitol of india",
            "national capital"
          ]
        }`